# PHP the mail() function

Tags: php, email

I'm using the mail-function of php:

```
$headers = "From: info@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
$sender = "info@example.com";
$receiver = $user->getEmail();
$subject = 'example mail';
mail($receiver, $subject, $sender, $headers);
```

the problem ist, the page were not loaded, if the e-mail address is invalid.

I tried to use it in a "if-" and "try-catch" clause, but it still does not work.

Comment: What's the problem?  What did you try?  What's `$user`?  What's `getEmail()`?  What do you mean by "email is invalid?  What do you mean by "the page were not loaded, if the e-mail address is invalid"?

Comment: `the page were not loaded, if the e-mail address is invalid` can you please elaborate this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should check if the receiver email is valid before sending.

Try using [filter_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for this. Example:

```
if (filter_var($receiver, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    mail($receiver, $subject, $sender, $headers);
} else {
    // the email is invalid, throw some error here
}
```